# How to convert links video from ok.ru to direct links to playing it on VideoPlayer android

Tags: java, android, url

I want play ok.ru videos on VideoPlayer but it's not working becoase the link is not direct. I want to convert this like 'http://ok.ru/videoembed/947875089023' to direct link. How can I do it?

Comment: Even though it might be a workaround to get a direct link here, I'd strongly recommend using an API documentation: https://apiok.ru/en/ . I'm pretty sure you will find a solution there.

Comment: Can you give me example?

Comment: Because i'm trying to use api but it's doesn't work.

Comment: I need to do like this website [downanyvideo](http://www.downanyvideo.com/download?url=https://ok.ru/video/947875089023)

Comment: https://apiok.ru/en/dev/methods/rest/video/video.getUploadUrl

Comment: Ok,He give me this https://api.ok.ru/fb.do?application_key=CBAGNEBNEBABABABA&format=json&method=video.getUploadUrl&sig=00b6bb99a1c79ca29df65ccf3374279e Where must be use this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found library to convert links to direct like and it's good. Also the library support other website not just ok.ru you can use it to get direct links.

Library name : xGetter Library for Android

xGetter library on github: https://github.com/KhunHtetzNaing/xGetter